# 500: Internal Server Error while trying to consume axis2 web service in .net

Tags: c#, web-services, apache-axis, edi

I am using c# console application to consume "axis2" web service by adding reference to the service file. It uses "wsse" security so i had to use "wse3 extension to call the service. But when i execute my application the response is always 500: internal server error.

The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

Why would i get this error response?

Comment: A 500 error is something that shouldn't happen happening on the server - say an unhandled exception. Check the server logs. (No pun intended -->)

Comment: Actually, i can't access the server. I don't have access to it. Could this be because the service url is wrong or something else?

Comment: Could be anything to be honest. Are you sending any parameters in?

Comment: Ya, i am sending an object which the action method expects. Before that i have added a passworddigestbehaviour to the endpoint of the service object for wse3 header.